# git merge after renaming of all files

Tags: git, merge, git-mv

There are other answers regarding handling `merge` for a rename, but my case is complicated enough that I thought it warranted a separate question.

We have a git project that originally consisted of 20+ repositories.  We used a wrapper script to handle many of the standard git operations.  Because we are now moving to GitHub, we cannot handle the project this way.

So, we moved all repositories into a single repository, essentially using the method described on [saintgimp](https://saintgimp.org/2013/01/22/merging-two-git-repositories-into-one-repository-without-losing-file-history/).  This, of course, means that all files have now been renamed, but the SHAs are identical historically.

OK, so now I want to merge branch `source` into branch `target`, noting that I made sure the two were in sync right before the final cutover.  My first attempt, using `git merge <source>` caused thousands of conflicts, complaints about files that were changed/deleted on one side or the other, etc.

Then I found a gem on the [Advanced Merging page](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Advanced-Merging):

> If you want to do something like this but not have Git even try to
>   merge changes from the other side in, there is a more draconian
>   option, which is the “ours” merge strategy. This is different from the
>   “ours” recursive merge option.

Ah, this sounds like what I need.  OK, I performed the following:

```
$ git merge -s ours SHA
```

where `SHA` is the last commit from the reunification.  In other words, I want all history, up to and including `SHA`, to be considered already merged into `target`.  My hope was that this would be a one-time merge and would fix all future merges.

Now, when I try to merge the first new commit from `source`, the effect is correct, but I continue to get the following warning:

```
[user@host src] git merge --no-commit next_unmerged_commit
Auto-merging /path/to/file/changed/foo.c
warning: inexact rename detection was skipped due to too many files.
warning: you may want to set your merge.renamelimit variable to at least 5384 and retry the command.
Automatic merge went well; stopped before committing as requested
```

And, in fact, if I set `renamelimit` to 10000, the next merge (call it `B`) is performed without warning, but at a cost of much slower performance.  Once again, a **one-time** cost is acceptable and I'll pay that cost if my subsequent merges are made *normal* again.

The next merge, `C`, where I use the default `renamelimit`, again gives the warning.

So, finally, my question: How can I convince git that the `target` branch is in sync with `source` so that it will stop trying to reach back in history before the reunification? I want to be able to merge without an increased `renamelimit`, due to the performance degradation.

Comment: I note that you used `--no-commit` in the second example. If you did that in the first (`git merge -s ours`), that would explain the problem. If not, it might help to provide a lot more detail on what you did to get into this situation (the first link you posted talks about using subtree merging so more detail could be important).

Comment: My question: are the new branches you're going to want to commit in the future, branches that were created before or after the initial mega-merge? In the situation you describe, I would expect such future merges to be fast, only merges from a branch that predates the mega merge to be slow. Does your workflow allow giving up on pre-mega-merge branches, or at least progressively phasing them out?

Comment: Second question, geared towards answering yours more directly: does `git merge-base master target` point to a commit before or after the mega-merge? Third question: are the file names in `source` and `target` the same, or pre & post renaming?

Comment: @torek The use of `--no-commit` was arbitrary and was not used in the initial `git merge -s ours` merge.

Comment: @joanis Both `source` and `target` were created before the mega-merge.  Yes, we will eventually give up on `source`, but not for a few months at least.

Comment: @joanis Question 2: It points to the second commit made on the new repository, but this commit occurred before any of the reunification/renaming occurred.  Note that we don't really use a single `master`.  We have multiple active release branches, each being sort of like its own master.  So, in my examples above, release branch R is `source` and R+1 is `target` and we need to be able to continuously merge changes made to release R into R+1.

Comment: @joanis Question 3: I believe that all merges after the initial `git merge -s ours` should be for commits which occurred post-reunification, meaning that the file names should be unchanged.  I intentionally chose SHA (in my example above) so that `git merge -s ours SHA` would include all activity that was part of the reunification.

Comment: @torek The script I used is based on one found [here](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/BhKvmMnqFQ/), which itself is based on the discussion I referenced in my post above ([saintgimp](https://saintgimp.org/2013/01/22/merging-two-git-repositories-into-one-repository-without-losing-file-history/)). I made my own modifications, but the general idea is the same.  Hope that helps.  Essentially, if I started with 20 repositories, I ended up with one repository that has 20 subdirectories,each named for one of the original repos.  Note that I did not use `subtrees`, if that is a git term.

Comment: FYI:  We ended up using the method I describe above (the 'ours' merge strategy) and then ignoring the warnings on all merges after that.  For the first several merges, we were very careful to examine the results of each merge to ensure we were getting what we asked for.  At this point, the older release branch is winding down, so we won't have the problem in future.

Many thanks to all who commented and @torek who spent a lot of time with his answer.  If I had the merge to do over, I think something like what torek describes would have been better, but the water was already under the bridge.

Answer (score 2):

This really isn't a very good answer as it's more about the script you used—or perhaps I should say, the script you *didn't* use, as [your comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55285121/git-merge-after-renaming-of-all-files?noredirect=1#comment97328067_552851) says that you used one *based on* [the script to which you linked](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/BhKvmMnqFQ/)—but I'll show the rather tangled graph I get in a hypothetical script-conversion of some original repositories below.  Note that this particular script leaves all the conversions with a merge base commit of, in essence, commit `B`, and commit `B` itself is *empty*.

Your question says:

> now I want to merge branch `source` into branch `target`, noting that I made sure the two were in sync right before the final cutover.

As you'll see below, all the new branches are named after the project that they came from—there's no clear way to map `source` and `target` onto, e.g., P or Q.  But if you were to run:

```
git checkout P/master
git merge Q/master
```

after the process illustrated below, the merge base for this `git merge` would be empty-commit-`B` and the merge would go smoothly: Git would look at the commits I drew as `D` and `H` respectively, trace their ancestries, find commit `B` as their merge base, and run two `git diff`s:

```
git diff <hash-of-B> <hash-of-D>   # what we did on P/master
git diff <hash-of-B> <hash-of-H>   # what they did on H/master
```

The output of these `git diff`s would say that *every file is created from scratch*, and all their names are different: everything in `P/master` is named `P/*` and everything in `H/master` is named `Q/*`.  There would be no name collisions and the merge would complete on its own.

Clearly, that's not what you're doing, then.  But what you *are* doing, and which commit is the merge base, remains mysterious.  It looks like you're picking out two tip commits such that the merge base of the two tip commits is a commit that *does* have files, *and* those files are not yet renamed from base to tip.

The point of the script you linked is to set things up so that the merge bases of each of the unrelated projects is an *empty* commit.  Probably, the thing to do after that script—or in place of that script, really—is to do one massive octopus merge of all the final commits (NB: this is untested, as is probably obvious):

```
git checkout P/master                 # just to be somewhere that's not master
git branch -d master                  # discard existing master branch name
git checkout --orphan master          # arrange to create new master
git merge P/master Q/master R/master  # make big octopus merge to marry all projects
```

The merge base of this octopus merge would again be commit `B`, and the result would be one merge that brings all the projects in under their new `project/*` names.  The original repositories are now all mostly useless, though if there are new commits in them, you can fetch from them, add a renaming commit, and merge from the renaming commit (this would be easier if the importing script *didn't* delete the added remotes).

#### Observations on the workings of the linked script

I've never faced this particular problem, but the approach in the script seems like a not-unreasonable starting point.  I'd probably do it a bit differently, not bothering with an empty merge base and using `git read-tree` and `git commit-tree` to build and create the end octopus merge.  The main key is to add a rename commit at the end of each incoming project branch (`P/*`, `Q/*`, etc) in the sketch below.

The script seems to work this way.  It has as inputs projects P, Q, R (URLs whose last component is treated a project name).

1. Make empty repo.
2. Make two iniial commits:

   ```
   A--B   <-- master
   ```

Commit A has one file, commit B has no files (why not just
commit the empty tree as B? but never mind).

3. Loop, for all three projects.  Here I have expanded the loop to view
   what's happening.
4. (loop iteration 1) `git remote add P <url>` and `git fetch P` (with `--tags`!?).  We're going to assume here that P has master and dev.

   ```
   A--B   <-- master

   P1-P2-...-Pm   <-- origin/P/master
          \
           Pd   <-- origin/P/dev
   ```
5. Use git ls-remote --heads to find names for commits in P, i.e.,
   the same set of names we have in `refs/remotes/P/*`.  (Assumes the
   remote hsa not changed during fetch -- unwise but probably OK.)

   Loop over these names.  Result again expanded in line for illustration...
6. Run `git checkout -b P/master master`.  Effect:

   ```
   A--B   <-- master, P/master

   P1-P2-...-Pm   <-- origin/P/master
          \
           Pd   <-- origin/P/dev
   ```
7. Run `git reset --hard` for no apparent reason: no effect.  Perhaps
   this might have some effect on some later step.
8. Run `git clean -d --force` for no apparent reason: no effect.
9. Run `git merge --allow-unrelated-histories --no-commit remotes/P/master"
   (does merge, but does not commit yet) and then run`git commit -m ...`.
   Effect:

   ```
   A--B   <-- master
       \
        \-------C   <-- P/master
               /
   P1-P2-...-Pm   <-- origin/P/master
          \
           Pd   <-- origin/P/dev
   ```
10. Maybe rename files, with somewhat squirrelly code (lines 160-180):
    if project P has one top level directory named P, do nothing, otherwise
    create directory named P (with no check to see if this fails) and
    then in effect:

    ```
    git mv all-but-P P/
    git commit -m "[Project] Move ${sub_project} files into sub directory"
    ```

    giving:

    ```
    A--B   <-- master
        \
         \-------C--D   <-- P/master
                /
    P1-P2-...-Pm   <-- origin/P/master
           \
            Pd   <-- origin/P/dev
    ```

    Note that the `git mv` is given `-k` so that it does nothing if
    one of the `git mv` operations would have failed.  However, except
    for subdirectory P and `.git` itself, all files in the top level
    of the work-tree should be in the index and the `git mv` should
    succeed unless one of them is named `P` (in which case, yikes!).

    I assume here that we did the mv, otherwise commit `D` does not exist.
11. Repeat loop (see step 5) for `dev`.  Run `git checkout -b P/dev master`:

    ```
    A--B   <-- master, P/dev
        \
         \-------C--D   <-- P/master
                /
    P1-P2-...-Pm   <-- origin/P/master
           \
            Pd   <-- origin/P/dev
    ```
12. Presumably-ineffectual `git reset` and `git clean` again
    as in steps 7 and 8.  (This might do something if the `git mv`
    in step 10 went really badly?)  Do a funky two step merge as in
    step 9, giving:

    ```
    A--B   <-- master
       |\
       | \-------C--D   <-- P/master
                /
    P1-P2-...-Pm   <-- origin/P/master
           \
         \  Pd   <-- origin/P/dev
          \   \
           \---E   <-- P/dev
    ```

    where the line down from B connects to the one up from E.  The
    graph has gotten rather out of hand at this point.
13. Rename and commit as in step 10.  I assume here that the
    project isn't already in a subdirectory, in both `master`, as
    already assumed, and `dev`.

    ```
    A--B   <-- master
       |\
       | \-------C--D   <-- P/master
                /
    P1-P2-...-Pm   <-- origin/P/master
           \
         \  Pd   <-- origin/P/dev
          \   \
           \---E--F   <-- P/dev
    ```
14. Really ugly attempt to rename tags, at lines 190-207.  This
    should have been done at fetch time, using a clever refspec.
    Whoever wrote this probably was not aware of annotated vs
    lightweight tags.  It is not clear to me whether this works
    correctly and I did not look closely.  Let's just assume no tags
    for now.
15. Remove remote P.  This removes the `origin/P/*` names too,
    but of course the commits stick around as they're retained by
    the new `P/*` branches:

    ```
    A--B   <-- master
       |\
       | \-------C--D   <-- P/master
                /
    P1-P2-...-Pm
           \
         \  Pd
          \   \
           \---E--F   <-- P/dev
    ```
16. Repeat outer loop (step 3) with remote Q.  We'll add Q and
    fetch (again with `--tags`, not a good plan as noted in step
    14, but let's just assume no tags).  So now we get another
    disjoint subgraph with `origin/Q/*` names.  For simplicity
    let's just assume that only `origin/Q/master` exists this time:

    ```
    A--B   <-- master
       |\
       | \-------C--D   <-- P/master
                /
    P1-P2-...-Pm
           \
         \  Pd
          \   \
           \---E--F   <-- P/dev

    Q1-Q2-...-Qm   <-- origin/Q/master
    ```
17. Run `git checkout -b Q/master master`:

    ```
    A--B   <-- master, Q/master
       |\
       | \-------C--D   <-- P/master
                /
    P1-P2-...-Pm
           \
         \  Pd
          \   \
           \---E--F   <-- P/dev

    Q1-Q2-...-Qm   <-- origin/Q/master
    ```
18. Run the (probably ineffectual and still mysterious)
    `git reset --hard` and `git clean` steps.
19. Use the funky two step merge with `--allow-unrelated-histories`
    to create new commit `G` like this:

    ```
         ---------------G   <-- Q/master
        /               |
    A--B   <-- master   | (down to Qm)
       |\
       | \-------C--D   <-- P/master
                /
    P1-P2-...-Pm
           \
         \  Pd
          \   \
           \---E--F   <-- P/dev

                 / (up to G)
                /
    Q1-Q2-...-Qm   <-- origin/Q/master
    ```
20. Again, optional: rename all files in G to live in Q/ and
    commit.  Again let's assume this *does* happen:

    ```
         ---------------G--H   <-- Q/master
        /               |
    A--B   <-- master   | (down to Qm)
       |\
       | \-------C--D   <-- P/master
                /
    P1-P2-...-Pm
           \
         \  Pd
          \   \
           \---E--F   <-- P/dev

                 / (up to G)
                /
    Q1-Q2-...-Qm   <-- origin/Q/master
    ```
21. Ugly attempt to rename tags; we'll ignore this.
22. Remove remote `Q` and `origin/Q/*` names.  (No need to draw this.)
23. Repeat outer loop for repository R.  Assuming it has only
    its own `master`, we'll get a tangled graph like this:

    ```
         --------------------I--J   <-- R/master
        /                    | (down to Rm)
       /
       | ---------------G--H   <-- Q/master
       |/               |
    A--B   <-- master   | (down to Qm)
       |\
       | \-------C--D   <-- P/master
                /
    P1-P2-...-Pm
           \
         \  Pd
          \   \
           \---E--F   <-- P/dev

                 / (up to G)
                /
    Q1-Q2-...-Qm
                    / (up to I)
                   /
    R1-R2-...----Rm
    ```

(end of analysis)